# Regular expression: ignore repeated words except for the final repeated word?

Tags: regex

I hope someone can help me with this.

I have the following text:

*XX Oferta de empleo como Gestor Económico teste y financiero en Importante empresa, Jerez de la Frontera XX*

I would like to match `Importante empresa` only.

The following regular expression will work fine:

```
XX.* en ([^,]+), .*XX
```

However if the text has `en` twice, for example:

*XX Oferta de empleo como Gestor Económico **en** teste y financiero **en** Importante empresa, Jerez de la Frontera XX*

it will match the following:

```
teste y financiero en Importante empresa
```

Do any of you know how I can make my regular expression only use the `en` closest to the comma when matching, so I will only match `Importante empresa` no matter how many `en`'s are before it?

Thank you.

Comment: When I test it here it appears to be working... are you pulling your result from group 1? What language are you using? http://www.regex101.com/r/dJ8iI2

Comment: tested the second case using http://www.regextester.com/index2.html and also got a correct result of `Importante empresa` from submatch set \1... sounds like either a typo somewhere, language specific regex issue, or a problem with flags?

Answer (score 0):

With your example, it should be working because the greedy `.*` at the start of the regex will match past all the `en`s and then only backtrack until the last `en` in the string to allow the rest of the regex to match. I can only think of one situation where it would fail, and that's when using the `/U` modifier in PHP that makes the greedy quantifiers lazy and vice versa.

But in any way, you can make your requirement explicit:

```
XX.* en ((?:(?!\ben\b)[^,])+), .*XX
```

Now the negative lookahead `(?!\ben\b)` asserts that there can be no further `en` anywhere in-between `en` and `,` (using `\b` word boundaries to avoid false positive matches like in  `encuentro` or `dicen`).